# How do I copy all files and directories, except certain ones over ssh?

Tags: ssh, synchronization, file-copy, remote

Using the Linux command line, I use the `scp` command, to copy all the files and folders from a certain directory. However, I don't like to consume bandwidth, for copying things I rarely change like my `tiny_mce` folder. What's the trick to copy everything, but skip a short list of folders?

Answer (score 21):

`rsync` works fine, and in most cases, uses SSH automatically as it's transport protocol. It will compare files and only upload those that have changed - but you can also use an [exclude list](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) to specify files in the tree that shouldn't be rsynced anyhow.

Comment: rsync does _not_ use SSH automatically - you have to supply the "-e ssh" flags to do that.

Comment: Yes, it does.

Rsync 2.6.0 released - The default remote shell is now "ssh" unless you tell configure you want to make something else the default.

http://www.samba.org/rsync/

Answer (score 14):

You could try [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) which only copies files that have changed, also works over ssh.

Answer (score 11):

Using `rsync --exclude` is the more obvious choice here, but if you really want to just send a few files or folders and have something specific to exclude, you can use shell globing with `scp`. First make sure you have the right globing options set in your shell. For bash run `shopt -s extglob` and for zsh use `setopt ksh_glob`. Then something like this:

```
scp /path/to/folder/!(tiny_mce|other_folder|*.bak) user@host:target_path
```

...would copy everything in the source folder except for things matching the given pattern. Obviously you can get creative with that part.

Answer (score 7):

`rsync` is a good solution, but if you're looking for an alternative:

Let's say, we have a directory "test" contain the directories "foo, bar, baz". In these dirs are a bunch of different file types:

```
test
|____bar
| |____1.jpg
| |____1.png
| |____1.txt
| |____2.jpg
| |____2.png
| |____2.txt
|____baz
| |____1.avi
| |____2.avi
| |____3.png
|____foo
| |____test.blah
|____test.txt
```

We want to copy everything except the PNGs

```
scp $(find /location/of/test -type f ! -name "*.png") # -> Note the logical NOT!!
```

In this example, the command will put all of the files into the same destination directory - this may not be the behavior you want.

Comment: Note that this answer only works if the file and directory names involved don't contain any shell special characters (whitespace or `\[*?`).

Answer (score 4):

A great tool you may want to try out is "lftp".

```
lftp sftp://etc.etc/ 
lftp> ls 
    --- remote listing ---
lftp> mirror -R -n local/ remote/
```

You can also use RSync over ssh

```
rsync -avzp -e ssh /this/dir/  remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir/
```

Should work.

Comment: To exclude files/folders with lftp, you can do e.g. `mirror -R -n src/ dest -X somefolder/ -X somefile`.  Note that if `dest` ends in a slash then the basename of `src` will be appended, e.g. `dest/src/...`

Answer (score 0):

I just finished [writing how I prefer **unison** to rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30661/13496) any day, since it

- doesn't need a daemon, other than ssh for transport
- lets me modify files on either side any time--*multiple masters* easily, while I only need to push a sync request from one side
- I am a stickler when it comes to modtimes, attributes/permissions, softlinks etc. No problems with that; for one project I even use 4 mirrors, one being a cygwin host. See my example crontab setup.
- supports exclusions like `*.bak`. Samples in my config file

Answer (score 0):

Using Secure Copy - **scp**

`scp -r file user@host:`

To copy many file

`scp /directory/* user@host:destinationPath`

To copy some files

`scp /directory/!(*.doc) user@host:destinationPath`

It copies content of directory except  **.doc** files

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly recommend you rsync.

rsync -vra --exclude="what you want to exclude" -e ssh folder user@remotehost:/folder

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me when I ran it from destination server.

```
rsync -av --progress user@servername:/sourcefolder /destinationfolder --exclude thefoldertoexclude
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in two steps to ignore `tiny_mce` directory.
Assuming all the directories start by lower case letters.

```
scp -r USER@HOSTNAME:~/FOLDER/[a-s]* .
scp -r USER@HOSTNAME:~/FOLDER/[u-z]* .
```

Also, change USER, HOSTNAME, and FOLDER to the real values.